# Define large number of interface implementations

Tags: c++, templates, macros, polymorphism

Suppose I have a simple interface with two methods:

```
class iface {
public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  virtual void bar() = 0;
};
```

Now I want to define a large number of implementations of that interface, but the only difference in the class declarations will be the names.  So, that means no extra methods, variables or other `protected` expressions.

For example:

```
class bar1 : public iface {
public:
  void foo();
  void bar();
};

class bar2 : public iface {
public:
  void foo();
  void bar();
};
```

Etc, up to barN where N could be about 50-60 classes.

Obviously the implementations are all going to be different, but there's still the problem of a ton of boilerplate definitions going on in the header.  I'd like to be able to somehow avoid defining these classes over and over again if possible.  I was thinking that perhaps I could use macros or templates to automate the generation so I can just type the next class in the list `bar3` into a function that would generate code that could be compiled and linked against.  However, I was reading and I guess it's not recommended to macro class definitions for debugging purposes.  Templates intuitively feel like a possible solution, but I still have to define the template somewhere.

Comment: Write a small script in your scripting language of choice that spits out a properly formatted header file, perhaps?

Comment: _@Brian_ You probably simplified your example too much. What should be the template parameter actually? A type or non type parameter?

Comment: The boost preprocessor library can probably do that.

Comment: I may be missing something but I don't really see what making some kind of automated/macro solution is going to buy you. You still have to type in a different name and write the member functions for each class. So I suspect cut'n'paste is going to be about as efficient as you can get.

Comment: @Galik Cut and paste is definition an option, and one that I'm not opposed to.  However, despite how much I think I know my requirements, they could still change in the future.  Say I wanted to add another pure virtual method to my interface.  Is there a better way update the class overhead automatically?  You're right I'll have to write the implementations but there's no way around that anyway.  Overall it seems like a scripting approach is less error prone and better at adapting to changes.

Comment: I'd choose the macro solution. It will not complicate the debugging because it will not be used for the actual function code, only for the header, and the header is not debugged.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well if it was a type parameter then the type needs to be defined somewhere, so I just see this as pushing the problem down another layer.  Maybe one solution is to use template function parameters and just use the appropriate functions directly.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is really this simple (i.e., was not over-simplified), then you might just do something like:

```
template<int i,
   typename std::enable_if_t< (i >= 0 && i < 50) > // this line is very much optional
>
class bar : public iface {
public:
  void foo();
  void bar();
};
```

I'd also suggest to mark foo() and bar() with virtual and/or override everywhere. If you want to simplify implementations as well, then you might first delegate (from the virtual override) to a template function, but some additional info would be useful to elaborate on that further.